# Ocultar campos en formulario utilizando Primefaces

Tags: formularios, primefaces

Tengo un inconveniente  estoy realizando un formulario en primefaces y me sucede lo siguiente:

**Codigo  de la vista xhtml**

```
<p:panel>

   <p:selectOneRadio layout="responsive" columns="2" value="#{empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Si" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0" />
  </p:selectOneRadio>

  <p:inputText  required="true" value="#{empresaWizard.empresa.nbComercial}"  label="Nombre de la Empresa" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa" size="50"  "/>
</p:panel>
```

Quisiera que cuando es estado sea 1  mi input se oculte pero no logro hacerlo,algun aporte que pueda ayudarme, utilizo rendered="#{empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch} eq 1.De ante mano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas evaluar la condición de rendered del input cada vez que el valor del `selectOneRadio` cambia de valor.

Dado que la condición de rendered chequea el valor de `empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch`, es decir, el valor de un miembro de tu backing bean, necesitas levantar un evento [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) cuando cambias el valor del `radio-button` de modo que el bean tenga el valor adecuado.

Luego, necesitas volver a evaluar la condición de rendered con el valor actualizado.

Para resolver esto puedes utilizar [p:ajax](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/ajax.html) e indicar que elementos actualizar al finalizar la respuesta mediante el atributo `update`

```
<p:panel>

   <p:selectOneRadio layout="responsive" columns="2" value="#{empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Si" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="0" />
    <p:ajax update=":nombre-empresa" />    
  </p:selectOneRadio>

  <p:inputText  id="nombre-empresa" required="true" value="#{empresaWizard.empresa.nbComercial}" label="Nombre de la Empresa" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa" size="50"  rendered="#{empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch eq 1} "/>
</p:panel>
```

A su vez, para evaluar si se eligió la opción `1` debes colocar el operador equals (eq) dentro del Expression Languaje (EL [spel](/questions/tagged/spel)):

```
#{empresaWizard.empresa.stAceptoMultiswitch eq 1}
```

Comment: Si al escribirlo aqui lo puse mal pero  si lo pongo como me lo mencionas y no logro hacerlo dinamico

Comment: En tu código falta el p:ajax que actualiza el componente. Revisa de nuevo la respuesta.